# how to highlight the given word in the web view using Java FX Panel

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am displaying html web pages in java swing using JAVA FX controls now i want to highlight a given word in the webview using JFXPanel with the help of javaFx. To display the html page i am using the following code.

```
 public class abc extends JFrame
  {
   JFXPanel fxpanel;
   Container cp; 
  public abc()
   {
    cp=this.getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    fxpanel= new JFXPanel();
    cp.add(fxpanel);
    fxpanel.setBounds(600,200,400,500);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable())
    {

   public void run()
   {
     init Fx(fxpanel);
   }}
   );


   }

   public static void main(String args[])
    {
    abc frm= new abc();
   frm.show();
    }

    private static void initFX(final JFXPanel fxpanel) 
     {
       Group group = ne Group();
       Scene scene= new Scene(group);
       fxpanel.setScene(scene);
      WebView webview= new WebView();
      group.getChildren().add(webview);
     webview.setMinSize(500,500);
     webview.setMaxSize(500,500);
     eng=webview.getEngine();
     File file= new File("d:/new folder/abc.html");
     try
     {
     eng.load(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
     }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX Web Engine is capable of establishing comminucation between `JavaFX` and `JavaScript`.
So may be you can use a JavaScript to select the words in the HTML page and execute that script from the JavaFX.

---

[Webview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

[JavaFX <-> JavaScript](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx)